# Finding expected number of comparisons while checking if two arrays are equal

Tags: probability

This is how I proceeded:

Assuming that the probability that `A[i] = B[i]` is the same for any **i** $\in$[1,n] (let's call it **p**)

Minimum number of comparisons is **1** and maximum is **n**.

So, expected value should be

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i.p^{i-1}
$$

I was doubtful about this approach partly because for some values I was getting unreasonable expected values ($n=10,p=0.9,ans=30.264311980000006$)

Is my approach correct? Is there an easier way to calculate the expected value?

Edit: I forgot to mention the algorithm. The algorithm sequentially compares the arrays starting from index **1** up to index **n** and as soon as a mismatch is found, it terminates.

Edit 2: I had missed the term $1-p$ in the summation. Now the summation would be
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i.p^{i-1}.(1-p)$

Comment: So what you're referring to is the expected number of times that $A[i]=B[i]$ before finding one value of $i$ for which they are not? And are you drawing A and B randomly or something?

Comment: Yes. The expected number of times A[i] = B[i] will be checked. You can assume that elements for A and B are drawn from a particular range [a,b] with uniform randomness

Comment: Your approach is not correct, your sum of probabilities is not $1$.

Comment: You have a point. But then what will be the probability that i comparisons is successful? That surely depends upon the success of all the previous comparisons. Because if even 1 of the comparisons before ith fails, the algorithm will terminate

Comment: Your expected value should be $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i.p^{i-1}.(1-p)$. You have missed the (1-p) part.

Comment: Oh yes how could I miss that. Thanks a ton! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_1\ne B_1$ with probability $1-p$, and the algorithm terminates after $1$ comparison.
$A_1=B_1\land A_1\ne B_1$ with probability $p(1-p)$, and the algorithm terminates in $2$ comparisons.
$A_1=B_1\land A_2=B_2\land A_3\ne B_3$ with probability $p^2(1-p)$, and the algorithm terminates in $3$ comparisons.

...

$A_1=B_1\land A_2=B_2\land...  A_{n-2}=B_{n-2}\land A_{n-1}\ne B_{n-1}$ with probability $p^{n-2}(1-p)$, and the algorithm terminates in $n-1$ comparisons.

Otherwise, the algorithm terminates with probability $1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}p^{i-1}(1-p)$ after $n$ comparisons.

Globally,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}ip^{i-1}(1-p)+n\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}ip^{i-1}(1-p)\right)=n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)p^{i-1}(1-p).$$

You can use the closed formula for the [arithmetico-gemetric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence).

Comment: For the second part, won't the probability that all numbers are equal simply be p^n ? I understood what you wrote but what's wrong with taking p^n for n comparisons?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. The probability of all equal, i.e. probability of reporting $true$ is indeed $p^n$, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: Okay. And btw, you have subtracted the first term from 1 as if that was probability, but that is the expected value of number of comparisons till i = n-1. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: You read wrong. I have subtracted the probabilities, not the expectations.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E(n,p)$ denote the expected number of comparisons for given $n$ and $p$. Then clearly $$\tag1E(1,p)=1$$ (I'm not sure if it is "even more clear" that $E(0,p)=0$). For $n>1$ we have $$\tag2E(n,p)=1+p\cdot E(n-1,p)$$ because we must make one comparison and iff the result is "equal" (i.e. with probability $p$), test the remaining arrays of size $n-1$. The properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold for $E(n,p)=\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}$.

Comment: Did you take into consideration the algorithm I posted in the edit? I think I don't understand how to calculate expected values. Isn't it equal to the sum of (product of probability of ith outcome and the outcome) for all possible outcomes?

Comment: Very elegant solution!